# MongoDB: User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

I'm making a social media app using MERN Stack and Redux with Redux Toolkit.

I made addRemoveFriend function that checks if the user is already friend then remove it, otherwise it will add it, but it doesn't work and give me this error:

```
"User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required."
```

addRemoveFriend:

```js
export const addRemoveFriend = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id, friendId } = req.params;
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    const friend = await User.findById(friendId);

    if (user.friends.includes(friendId)) {
      user.friends = user.friends.filter((id) => id !== friendId);
      friend.friends = friend.friends.filter((id) => id !== id);
    } else {
      user.friends.push(friendId);
      friend.friends.push(id);
    }
    await user.save();
    await friend.save();

    const friends = await Promise.all(
      user.friends.map((id) => User.findById(id))
    );
    const formattedFriends = friends.map(
      ({ _id, firstName, lastName, username, avatarPath }) => {
        return { _id, firstName, lastName, username, avatarPath };
      }
    );

    res.status(200).json(formattedFriends);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ error: err.message });
  }
};
```

User Model:

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    ...,
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 8,
      max: 50,
    },
    friends: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

[AddRemoveFriend (Frontend)](https://jsfiddle.net/pq76cgd8/)

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting it right then password field in your mongoose collection is marked as required.

When you get user with  below query then it will return mongoose documents which are immutable.

```
const user = await User.findById(id);
const friend = await User.findById(friendId);
```

The reason you are getting this error is that result returned by above queries will not be plain javascript object which you might be expecting.

Use .lean() to make mongoose return a Javascript object that can be modified:

```
const user = await User.findById(id).lean();
const friend = await User.findById(friendId).lean();
```

Comment: It gives me ```"user.save is not a function"```